# How to show $x\mapsto Ax$ is an isometry

Tags: matrices, metric-spaces, isometry

Given  that   $A$  is  an  $n\times n$  *real*  orthogonal  matrix . $x$  is  any  column  vector  of  $\mathbb R^{n}$ .Define  $$x\mapsto Ax$$  This is  an  isometry  on  $\mathbb R^{n}$ .

Then  I  have  to  show  $$d(Ax_1,Ax_2)=d(x_1,x_2)$$ i.e. $$||Ax_1-Ax_2||=||x_1-x_2||(||\ \ ||\ \ is\ \ the\ \ \ Euclidean\ \ norm\ \ on\ \ \mathbb R^n)$$
 i.e. $$||A(x_1-x_2)||=||(x_1-x_2)||$$

$A$  is  an  element  of  $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$  and  $(x_1-x_2)$  ,  of  $\mathbb R^n$.

What  should  I  do  next  $?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$
\|Ax\|^2 = \langle Ax, Ax \rangle  =  \langle A^TAx, x \rangle = \langle x, x \rangle = \|x\|^2
$
and so
$
\|Ax\| = \|x\|
$.

Now take $x=x_1-x_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $ x_i = A^Ty_i$, we can get anything in $\mathbb{R}^n$ via this relation because $A$ is a bijection (because it is orthogonal, so the inverse is $A^T$).

So just plug $x_i = A^Ty_i$ into your norm, and you're done.